# Extracting single letters out of a string in python

Tags: python

Is there a possibility to extract single letters out of a string that the user of the program defines in python? For example i want to extract the single letters of this string:

```
     x = raw_input("Letters i want to extract")
```

Comment: `for single_letter in x`?

Answer (score 3):

A string is a sequence in Python the indexing starts from zero. To get a specific element or (character) of a string just use the following:

```
>>> x = "This is a string"
>>> first_letter = x[0]
>>> second_letter = x[1]
>>> last_letter = x[-1]
>>> print first_letter
T
>>> print last_letter
g
>>>
```

You can also loop through it very easily like so:

```
>>> for index, letter in enumerate(x):
    print index, letter

0 T
1 h
2 i
3 s
4  
5 i
6 s
7  
8 a
9  
10 s
11 t
12 r
13 i
14 n
15 g
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'test'
>>> s[0]
't'
>>> list(s)
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
>>> for ch in s:
...     print ch
...
t
e
s
t
```

Answer (score 1):

x = raw_input("Letters i want to extract")

```
for i in x:
    print i 
    #or do whatever you please
```

I think this is what your looking for. The code snip-it iterates through the string and outputs  each letter. Instead of printing you could do what ever you would like.

You can also access each letter individuality through the syntax x[index_value].

ie.

```
x[0] would yield 'L'
x[1] would yield 'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

A variable has a name and a value.

A dictionary is a collection of names associated with values. So, for your purposes you might be able to make a dictionary and treat it as "a collection of variables".

For example, if you want the "single variables" for each letter in x to be *counters*, then you could use this code:

```
def stats():
    x = raw_input("Letters i want to extract: ")
    data = raw_input("Text I want to do some stats on: ")

    # make a dictionary of letters in x
    d = {}
    for chr in x:
      d[chr] = 0 # initialize counter

    # collect stats
    for item in data:
      if item in d:
        d[item] += 1

    # show results in a couple of ways
    print "The full tally: %r" % d
    for chr in x:
      print "There were %d occurrences of %c in the text" % (d[chr], chr)
```

Here's an example run.

```
>>> stats()
Letters i want to extract: bell
Text I want to do some stats on: hello world
The full tally: {'b': 0, 'e': 1, 'l': 3}
There were 0 occurrences of b in the text
There were 1 occurrences of e in the text
There were 3 occurrences of l in the text
There were 3 occurrences of l in the text
```

Comment: I swear the OP originally asked to be able to treat the elements of `x` as variables - hence the slant on this answer. Not sure why the Edit History on the post doesn't show this any more!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop like this

```
x = raw_input("Letters i want to extract")
for ch in x:
    print x
```

You can also get individual characters like this

```
x[0] # first character
x[1] # second character
```

You can convert to a list like this

```
char_list = list(x)
```